# Bootstrap col, row not working with good parents and childs

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Some functionalities from Bootstrap are working like -xl but i'm doing multiples class with col-lg-4 and col-md-4 and is it not working.

I want them to be all in one row but they're not moving with the classes.

I already have put the parent as `row` and child as `col` but still not doing nothing.

[images that have to be in one row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm4dD.png)

[all my links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55mpJ.png)

[all my scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8upO.png)

Code not working:

```
   <!----------- Series Film Prochainement ----------->
<section id="UpcomingMovies">
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Films/Series a venir</h2>
        <div class="row Movies">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6"><a href="#"><img src="/Images/UpcomingMoviesImages/LeSeigneurDesAnneauxVF.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
                    <div class="col-6"><a href="#"><img src="/Images/UpcomingMoviesImages/MoonKnightVF.jpg" alt=""></a>
                 </div>
               </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6"><a href="#"><img src="/Images/UpcomingMoviesImages/Liledes30cercueilsVF.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
                    <div class="col-6"><a href="#"><img src="/Images/UpcomingMoviesImages/HaloVF.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
                 </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6"><a href="#"><img src="/Images/UpcomingMoviesImages/StarWarsObiWanKenobiVF.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
                    <div class="col-6"><a href="#"><img src="/Images/UpcomingMoviesImages/StrangerThings4VF.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: you don't seem to be closing your top level cols or row divs in the correct place

Comment: as a side note, if you're just having 6 columns, why nest them - you could just use col-2

Comment: Ohh yeah sorry I didn't saw it. Exhausted that missing the biggest errors. Thanks !

Comment: I have made some minor edits in your code.  I closed the rows and changed the class `Container` => `container`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Rows inside Columns inside Columns inside Rows. This is bound to make things confusing. For example `col-6` is making a box half the width of the page. But you have that inside a `col-md-4` so actually your `col-6` will only be making one half of that parent column. You need to reorganise your rows and columns. I've done the below example so that you get all your divs get stacked vertically on mobile screens but side by side on medium screens and above.

```
<section id="UpcomingMovies">
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Films/Series a venir</h2>
        <div class="row Movies">
               <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6"><a href="#"><img src="/Images/UpcomingMoviesImages/LeSeigneurDesAnneauxVF.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
               <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6"><a href="#"><img src="/Images/UpcomingMoviesImages/MoonKnightVF.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
               <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6"><a href="#"><img src="/Images/UpcomingMoviesImages/Liledes30cercueilsVF.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
               <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6"><a href="#"><img src="/Images/UpcomingMoviesImages/HaloVF.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
               <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6"><a href="#"><img src="/Images/UpcomingMoviesImages/StarWarsObiWanKenobiVF.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
               <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6"><a href="#"><img src="/Images/UpcomingMoviesImages/StrangerThings4VF.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help ! The images are 2 by 2 and 1 by 1 on mobile size. I can't get them like a smaller size to have 4 by 4 or 5 by 5 and some of my images are bigger or smaller than the other. I don't understand why